# What are good bicycle review and comparison sites?

Tags: road-bike, shopping

I'm thinking of buying a new road bike on the new year but I'm unsure which model to go for.

Are there any websites that maintain comparisons of currently available models?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's http://www.bikeradar.com/ which is linked to 4 magazines: Cycling Plus, Mountain Biking UK, Procycling and What Mountain Bike. As a result it carries various bike and gear reviews from the magazines as well as some which are only online (I think).

As all of the magazines are UK based the site obviously has a British bias.

Answer (score 5):

[www.roadbikereview.com](http://www.roadbikereview.com) (see also [mtbr.com](http://www.mtbr.com) for the Mountain bike version) doesn't have actual comparisons, but there are user reviews for a wide variety of models and bike parts.