# Does Nirve make a good bike?

Tags: commuter

I'm interested in small women's city bike and a 3-speed 2010 Nirve Wilshire just came up for sale, used.  I've never heard of this company and the interwebs are producing little info.  I searched for reviews, including on the sites recommended in this thread: [What are good bicycle review and comparison sites?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/what-are-good-bicycle-review-and-comparison-sites)

Can anyone attest to Nirve bikes or the Wilshire?

Comment: Just reading up on [their site](http://www.nirve.com/nirve-women-beach-cruiser-bike.asp?cat=city&cid=582.68) what seems like a red flag to me is that, apart from the brakes (and even then, only the manufacturer is listed), they don't list which models of components are used.  Without knowing what kind of actual equipment you're getting on the bike, it's impossible to tell if the bike is of good quality, and it's impossible to tell if it is overpriced or a good deal.